# Catalyst-Plugin-Authentication how do I check a history of encrypted passwords

Tags: perl, catalyst

we are using Catalyst-Plugin-Authentication for storing hashed passwords and it's working great.

Now we have a requirement to keep an X number of hashed password history and check new password against this list. I'm looking to find a way to loop through 10 (for example) previous hashed passwords for a user to check against new not yet hashed password. If there is a match, return error. How can this be done?

Comment: You have to build that yourself. Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication does not provide that functionality. Take a look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/177342/58485. That's what you want.